# Sitecore scaled CM environment with load balancer NULL reference issue

Tags: scaling, load-balancer

We have two **CM servers** with their own **Publishing Service** and `load balancer`.

When I publish an item directly on server machine it works fine. But when I access website externally *(request comes through balancer)* then I catch `null-reference` error.

`POST requests` from browser are identically. In log files I see that **model** that comes to CM controller action after `load balancer` **is null**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [DenyNonPublishingRoles]
    public HttpResponseMessage ItemPublish([FromBody] PublishingJobEntity entity)
    {
      Condition.Requires<PublishingJobEntity>(entity, nameof (entity)).IsNotNull<PublishingJobEntity>();
      Condition.Requires<string>(entity.ItemId, "itemId").IsNotNull<string>();
      HttpResponseMessage entity1 = this.CreateEntity(entity);
      entity1.Content = (HttpContent) new ObjectContent<PublishingJobEntity>(entity, (MediaTypeFormatter) new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");
      return entity1;
    }
```

ErrorMessage: `entity should not be null. ↵Parameter name: entity`.

**UPDATE**

Even if I try to republish old job I get:

[image]

In console it is a simple **POST** request to `https://mywebsite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/0/Republish` with single **jobId** parameter.

I can easy reproduce the same with POSTMAN. And again, when I do it on server - all is fine, when remotely - catch an error:

```
11320 17:15:37 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL https://mywebsite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/0/Republish

Exception System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Refit.ApiException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.RemoteProxies.PublishJobQueueServiceRemoteProxy.<GetJob>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Data.PublishingJobProvider.<Get>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Client.Services.Data.PublishingJobRepository.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<FindById>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Client.Services.Data.PublishingJobRepository.FindById(String id)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Client.Services.Controllers.PublishingJobController.Republish(Guid jobId)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Refit.ApiException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.RemoteProxies.PublishJobQueueServiceRemoteProxy.<GetJob>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Data.PublishingJobProvider.<Get>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Client.Services.Data.PublishingJobRepository.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<FindById>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---
```

Has anybody faced similar issue?

Comment: Is you load balancer sticky?

If it is not sticky, it may happen that one request is to CM1, second request is to CM2. But one of CM doesn't have context and that is why is throwing error.

Comment: Thank you, @Anton! It seems you are right, I will check it.

Comment: No, it is not a solution. Sticky session was enabled. I have no idea, is it a problem of Publishing Module or of load balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue was caused by **WAF** *(Web Application Firewall)* on load balanced server.

Still did not find what exactly is the reason on WAF side, but disabling of WAF solved the problem.

Comment: WAF and Application Gateway are compatible with CDs, they are not compatible with Content Management (CM) servers. Source: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/using-azure-application-gateway-to-secure-your-content-delivery-server.html